# Sed regexp issue with matching from ^ to " with anything between

Tags: sed, regular-expression

It's been a long time since I've used `sed` and regexp so I'm a little rusty. Simplifying, I have the following as input from which I'd like to extract the url:

```
href="https://unix.stackexchange.com/"
```

I've used the very useful tool at regex101.com to refine my expression down to initially remove everything between the `^` and the first `"` to this:

```
s/^.*="//
```

However, this isn't what I want as I don't want to be dependent on the `=` sign. But, if I modify the expression to be this:

```
s/^.*"//
```

It matches everything between `^` and the final `"` and ignores the first.

Obviously, I'm missing something here which I'm frustrated by but any help would be gratefully received.

Running Ubuntu 21.04 on arch64.

Comment: Try `s/^[^"]*"//`.

Comment: What _can_ you depend on? What will always be present in your input? If you don't want to rely on the `=`, what _can_ you rely on instead? Can we assume that the URL will be the longest string of non-`"` characters that can be found between two `"` characters? Will it always start with `https://`? Will it always end in `/`? Can we just take whatever comes after the first `"` on the line and end with the last `"`?

Comment: @Isaac spot on thank you and many thanks

Comment: Just a note: Using a regex to process *ML (SGML, XML, HTML, etc) is often a path to destruction--you'll be pulling out your hair if one site uses badly formed *ML, such as `<a hRef=# title="ha-ha! I left the quotes out of the HREF to mess up your regex attempt!">`, which is okay with most web browsers but sill malformed HTML. (Also note I intentionally used an uppercase R in hRef...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're missing is that `.*` matches *greedily*, consuming as many characters it can (including any `"` up to the last).

You can either exclude `"` from the "anything between" using `[^"]*`, or switch to a regex engine that provides a non-greedy modifier such as Perl `.*?`

```
$ printf '%s\n' 'href="https://unix.stackexchange.com/"' | sed 's/^[^"]*"//'
https://unix.stackexchange.com/"

$ printf '%s\n' 'href="https://unix.stackexchange.com/"' | perl -pe 's/^.*?"//'
https://unix.stackexchange.com/"
```

OTOH if what you really want is the bare URL, you can match and capture everything between the first and last quote, and use a backreference to re-substitute only that:

```
$ printf '%s\n' 'href="https://unix.stackexchange.com/"' | sed 's/^[^"]*"\(.*\)"/\1/'
https://unix.stackexchange.com/
```

The initial `^[^"]*` strictly no longer needs to be non-greedy and could be replaced by `^.*` in this context, since the regex as a whole can't consume the first `"` while still matching the second (although making it greedy may introduce unnecessary backtracking).

Comment: I suspect that the OP would prefer not to have the trailing quote either.

Comment: @terdon yes that seems likely although it's not explicit in the question as it stands - I've added a suggestion

Comment: @steeldriver I said I was missing something and your greedy explanaition is it. Very grateful for this it opens up a whole perspective on sed and regexp. I'll look into perl again as well. Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is the kind of job `cut` was invented to do:

```
$ cut -d'"' -f2 file
https://unix.stackexchange.com/
```

Comment: I love it, this is exactly the pragmatic approach I would have taken when I was coding for a living.

Answer (score 0):

You could match everything up to the **first** `"` with:

```
sed 's/^[^"]*"//'
```

That will match from the start of a line `^` several (zero or more `*`) characters that are **not** double quotes (`[^"]`) followed by a double quote `"`.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F "=" '{gsub("^\"","",$2);print $2}' filename
```

output

```
https://unix.stackexchange.com/"
```

Suppose if you want to remove trailing quotes we can use below command

```
awk -F "=" '{gsub("\"","",$2);print $2}' filename
```

output

```
https://unix.stackexchange.com/
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `gawk`:

```
awk '{print gensub(/(^.*")(.*")/, "\\2", "g");}' input
```

In this command, `gawk` built-in `gensub()` function replaces all captured groups with second captured group using backreferencing(`\\2`).

If we want to remove trailing quote, then the command may be changed to this:

```
awk '{print gensub(/(^.*")(.*)(")/, "\\2", "g");}' input
```

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to rely on the equal sign, this should work.

These first two run only with `grep` which support `PCRE`, and the `GNU grep` on yours `ubuntu` does:

```
printf "%s\n" 'href="https://unix.stackexchange.com/"' | grep -Po '(?<=")[^"]*'
```

Or

```
printf "%s\n" 'href="https://unix.stackexchange.com/"' | grep -Po '(?<=").+(?=")'
```

---

These run everywhere :

```
printf "%s\n" 'href="https://unix.stackexchange.com/"' | sed 's/[^"]*//; s/"//g'
```

Or

```
printf "%s\n" 'href="https://unix.stackexchange.com/"' | awk -F '"' '{print $2}
```